# Trying to divide UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibezierpath

In a functionality I am using UIBezierPath For drawing curves.In one scenario I need to break the   UIBezierPath into pieces with respect to a constant (in the device landscape x value 512.0 ).I am not sure it can be possible or not.Is there any wat to do the same.Please help me to run out of this situation.
Thanks in advance.

some code snippets which I am using in my app for drawing:

```
    [bezierPath moveToPoint:mid1];
    [drawingBezier addQuadCurveToPoint:mid2 controlPoint:previousPoint1];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "break the UIBezierPath into pieces with respect to a constant" ?

Answer (score 5):

every bezierpath has two points(start point and ending point).

At touch began event

```
    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [myPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];      // points (X1,y1)
```

At touch moved event

```
    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
   [myPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];   // points (X2,y2)
```

Now split the mypath line using (x1,x2) and (y1,y2) values.(i.e.) x1=500, x2= 700, y1=250, y2 = 500 and new x = (x1+x2/2) y = (y1+y2/2) (new point calculation as per your requirement) Call the drawRect to draw the  lines.